# Virtual Machine begins with installation again after restarting

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso-image

I have been trying to set up a virtual machine using VMware/VirtualBox. Everything runs fine- the set up etc. I use an ISO file for the setup, in case that matters.

But when I power off the machine and start it again at later time, it begins with the installation again. I know it is some fundamental mistake, but I am unable to decipher what is to be done.

Comment: Try ejecting the disc image (`iso`) from the virtual optical drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the vm settings to disconnect the cd drive, or in vm bios make your first boot option the virtual hard disk, before power it back on, if you used a cd or virtual cd to install the os.

Comment: Not disconnect, eject. There's a difference between removing a drive and making the drive empty.

Comment: Yup, sometimes it doesn't auto-eject, depending on whether you used the install from .iso wizard.

Comment: yes, if you can eject you can eject from the guest OS but depending on the virtual platform and your guest OS, it is not always possible to eject, and disconnect is the surest way if you don't want to change the bios settings, esp. if the drive is virtual. reconnect is the way to get the virtual cd drive back, as there is no "insert cd" because an iso file is being used.